# TYPO3 extension: Call to a member function setParent() on null

Tags: typo3, extbase

So bascially with a f:link.action, calling an edit Action of another controller i get the error

```
Call to a member function setParent() on null
```

The code in my FormFields.html looks like this

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <f:link.action  action="edit" controller="ExterneAktivitaet" arguments="{externeaktivitaet : externeaktivitaet}">
        <f:translate key="tx_kundentermine_domain_model_termin.externeaktivitaet" />
        </f:link.action>
        {termin.externeaktivitaet}
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The edit Action just has a view->assign, so the error has to be somewhere else. The interesting thing is that i have other f:link.actions calling different but identical classes/controllers and these work just fine. Can this be some internal TYPO3 error? I don't have a "parent" property defined anywhere, so i don't understand the setter and why something i have not even in my code can be called. Also i've never seen this error before.

Comment: Put your controller->action code so we can review this..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below typoscript in your `setup.ts` file. So, you can easily determine where is the error in your code.

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

Also set `displayErrors => 1` in `LocalConfiguration.php` file.

Comment: Interesting... It supposedly throws the error in /var/www/html/typo3_src-8.7.9/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Error/Result.php in line 223.

Answer (score 0):

Check, whether the arguments passed to the fluid render tags have all the arguments supplied. In my case the following code

```
<f:render partial="FormErrors" arguments="{object:object}" />
```

was throwing the same error. So the solution for me was to change it like this.

```
<f:render partial="FormErrors" arguments="{_all}" />
```

It might differ in your case. Hope this will get you to the right track.